# unable to set height of jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jssor

jsp code i use to draw slider is ...

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
<!-- Slides Container -->
  <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner01.png" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner02.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner03.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner04.png" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner05.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner06.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img u="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/sliderimages/banner07.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jquery function i use to display slider is

```
 function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
    console.log("**********"+parentWidth);
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }

    else
        $JssorUtils$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();
$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

i unable to increase the height of the slider please help....

Comment: It always keeps aspect ratio, you can call either $ScaleWidth or $ScaleHeight

Answer (score 2):

You can change the width and the height of jssor slider.

Locate these codes:

```
$SlideWidth: 600,
$SlideHeight: 300,
```